# PHP POST with fsockopen - 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, post, http-headers

I am moving an application from IIS/PHP 5.3 to AlmaLinux 8/PHP 8.0 but when testing I get `400 Bad Request`.

Application does a POST request using fsockopen() function. I created a simple script to test this portion of the code and I also get the error `400 Bad Request`. Test via Postman works as expected.

Here is the script which submits data:

```
<?php
$dest_url = "bgsrv26.internal.bitnetx.com";
$dest_path = "posttest.php";
$post_data = 'name=Test';

$fp = fsockopen($dest_url, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "POST $dest_path HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: $dest_url\r\n";
    $out .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n"; 
    //$out .= "Content-type: text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n\r\n"; 
    $out .= $post_data . "\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Second script simply prints out what is is the POST data:

```
<?php
//$_POST['name'] is Post with the help of fsockopen().
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
echo 'Welcome '.$_POST['name'];
}?>
```

Here's the error I am getting

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sun, 27 Aug 2023 03:12:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.37 (AlmaLinux) mod_fcgid/2.3.9
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

I have created a test script using cURL instead and it is working. However, I can't seem to change the content type to `text/xml`. I've created another post for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76985768/content-type-text-xml-not-working-for-php-curl).

Comment: You'll need a blank line between your headers and your POST body.  You might also need to specify the encoding.  You might also want to considering using cURL functions instead as it would make all this so much easier

Comment: Tried what you suggested with the header. I've added a blank line between the header and POST body. Also tried setting the content type to ```Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8``` and ```Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` but does not work. I got it to work with cURL but I can't seem to change the content type to ```Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8```.

Comment: I couldn't get it working with ```fsockopen``` but did get it working with cURL. [Here's][1] the other Post I opened previously.

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76985768/content-type-text-xml-not-working-for-php-curl

Comment: If you are sending `Content-type: text/xml`, then you can't expect PHP to populate $_POST. That _only_ happens when `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` are sent.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, $_POST won't work with ```text/xml```. It shouldn't be the reason why I am getting ```400 Bad Request``` though. In cURL, it sends the request but the response is empty. I have changed ```application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` but I still get ```400 Bad Request```

Comment: Can you check if the error log on the receiving end has any more details?