# Content type: text/xml not working for PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to set `Content-Type: text/xml` in PHP cURL but cannot seem to get it work. PHP version is 8.0 on AlmaLinux 8.

Here's the script which sends a post request to `post_test_xml.php`

```
<?php

$dest_url = "http://bgsrv26.internal.bitnetx.com/post_test_xml.php";
$xml = '<test sysVersion="1"/>';
$post_data = "xml_text=" . $xml . "\r\n";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$dest_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$xml);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,['Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8']); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,3);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
print "cURL response: " . $response . "\n\r";

$info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
print "cURL info: ";
var_dump($info);
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Here's the `post_test_xml.php` file.

```
<?php

//$_POST['name'] is Post with the help of fsockopen().

$xmltext = @$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;

If( $xmltext == "" ) { 
    if (isset($_POST['xml_text'])) {
        $xmltext = $_POST['xml_text'];
    }
}
$xmltext = stripslashes( $xmltext );

$myfile = fopen("xml_post.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $xmltext);
fclose($myfile);

echo 'Results: '. $xmltext;

?>
```

Here's the result of the request. Both `$xmltext` variable and xml_post.txt file are empty.

```
cURL response: Results:
cURL info: string(177) "POST /post_test_xml.php HTTP/1.1
Host: bgsrv26.internal.bitnetx.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 22
```

I did manage to get it to work when setting `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to changing post data as `$post_data = "xml_text=" . $xml . "\r\n"`

```
<?php

$dest_url = "http://bgsrv26.internal.bitnetx.com/post_test_xml.php";
$xml = '<test sysVersion="1"/>';
$post_data = "xml_text=" . $xml . "\r\n";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$dest_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING,'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded']); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,3);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
print "cURL response: " . $response . "\n\r";

$info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
print "cURL info: ";
var_dump($info);
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Results as follows:

```
cURL response: Results: <test sysVersion="1"/>

cURL info: string(187) "POST /post_test_xml.php HTTP/1.1
Host: bgsrv26.internal.bitnetx.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 33
```

Comment: Can you please define: _"cannot seem to get it work"_? What are the symptoms of it not working? What does it do, and what do you think it should do? See also: [“It’s not working” is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: Why would you wish to specify that particular Content-Type header for POSTing a value? The POST method should either be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain` - the latter perhaps the best option if you are trying to send a text representation of XML perhaps

Comment: Incidentally, `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` was deprecated ages ago and removed from PHP in version 7, so unless you have PHP pre 5.56 that variable will not be populated anyway so instead use `$xmltext = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Comment: It should print out ```<test sysVersion="1"/>```. As @ProfessorAbronsius mentioned, the reason is indeed due to the using the deprecated ```$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA``` in PHP 8.0. ```$xmltext = file_get_contents("php://input");``` fixes the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your POST body is no longer in form submission format, PHP will not populate it in `$_POST`. And since `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` has been deprecated. So yo need to read the stream "php://input".

```php
<?php

$xmltext = file_get_contents('php://input'); // ** Here

If( $xmltext == "" ) { 
    if (isset($_POST['xml_text'])) {
        $xmltext = $_POST['xml_text'];
    }
}
$xmltext = stripslashes( $xmltext );

$myfile = fopen("xml_post.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $xmltext);
fclose($myfile);

echo 'Results: '. $xmltext;
```